# How to Store Response Headers Token and use in Next Test Case Request Headers in Soap UI

Tags: groovy, soapui

KEY                        Value
Cookie                    Abp.AuthToken=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy5

In the above mentioned Value I need to Extract the token after Abp.AuthToken = "", what ever the token mentioned after equal to symbol, i need to fetch it and store it as variable or set property and use it in Next test case, Request Header as Bearer ""